# update dependent chain of inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a rather complicated user interface with long chains of dependent user inputs.

One feature I want to add is the ability to store all input values at any given time as a string, and use that string to reset all inputs as a result of an actionButton. Storing the string as JSON is easy, but restoring dependent inputs has proven tricky, and I'm wondering if there are any good ideas out there.

A tiny example app is provided below. You can see that the variable choices are dependent on the selected group (group1 or group2).

Upon clicking the actionButton, I want to set group = group2, and variable = group2_variable2.

But the click only accurately sets group, and variable is set to the first (default) choice.

I assume I have to wait until an independent input is fully reset before updating any dependent inputs, but is there a systematic way to do that all within one observe()? Or is there another preferred way to do it?

```
library(shiny)

groups <- c('group1', 'group2')

variables <- list(
  group1 = c('group1_var1', 'group1_var2'),
  group2 = c('group2_var1', 'group2_var2'))


ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel('Demo'),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      inputId = 'group',
      label   = 'Group:',
      choices = groups),

    uiOutput('variable_selector'),

    actionButton(
      inputId = 'reset_parameters',
      label = 'Reset Parameters')
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    h4('Demo')
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$variable_selector <- renderUI({

    selectInput(
      inputId = 'variable',
      label   = 'Variable:',
      choices = variables[[input$group]])
  })

  observe({
    if (input$reset_parameters > 0) {
      updateSelectInput(
        session,
        inputId = 'group',
        selected = 'group2')

      updateSelectInput(
        session,
        inputId = 'variable',
        selected = 'group2_var2')
    }

  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `renderUI` here so the `variable` input is correctly reset but then the entire `selectInput` is recreated.

To avoid this, you could use `updateSelectInput` to populate the `choices` of yout `variable` input.

In your `ui.R`, you could replace `uiOutput('variable_selector')` by:

```
selectInput(inputId = 'variable',
            label   = 'Variable:',
            choices = "")
```

And in `server.R`:

```
observeEvent(input$group,{updateSelectInput(
                session,
                inputId = 'variable',
                choices = variables[[input$group]])
        })
```

The `updateSelectInput` in the `observeEvent` is rerun when you press the button but it does not recreate the `selectInput` from scratch and only changes the `choices`so the selected option stays the same.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work! I have a feeling I'll run into complications with some inputs that only exist under certain conditions (so renderUI is used), but this does solve the simpler question that I posed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `inputId` given in the `updateSelectInput`.

Try using `variable_selector` instead of `variable`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't appear to work - variable_selector is an output (uiOutput), not an input. The actual selectInput I want to update has inputId = 'variable'. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: it seems that when you click the button, `updateSelectInput` is flushed and than the `renderUI` is flushed too afterwards! I think that you have to create a `selectInput` directly at the `UI-side` and have only the `updateSelectInput` on the `server-side`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your input has options `'group2_var1', 'group2_var2'` but when you reset them you are trying to set it to `'group2_variable2'`. Try the following change...

```
updateSelectInput(
    session,
    inputId = 'variable',
    selected = 'group2_var2')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good catch...edited above. But the problem still persists - when I click the button, the variable selector goes to 'group2_var1' instead of 'group2_var2'.

Comment: Thats true, it works if you hit the button twice for some reason though.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue - the reset can directly update an independent input, but a dependent one (variable selector) has to first get the right set of values from another input (group selector), and only then can it be updated correctly. So I could just keep clicking the button until works, but that won't work if the inputs are on other tabs and aren't updated until they become visible.